# Docker Registry Cross Repository Blob Mount feature. What happens when one of the registries are deleted?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry

When the `Cross Repository Blob Mount` feature is in use and the second registry mounts a lot of layers. What happens when the first registry gets deleted?

Logically, if it's just a mount and not a copy the layers are gone.

The weird thing here is both registries have different volumes. One of them is a volume mount whilst the other one uses a vanilla docker volume. How do docker know about the registry anyway?

Maybe someone help to clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the specific registry implementation. However, all of the implementations I've seen have a blob store that is separate from the repositories. When the repository is deleted, that reference to the blob is deleted, but others may still exists. Typically, a periodic garbage collection operation on the registry is used to delete blobs that are no longer referenced by any repository.